# Plot the solution curves of $\frac {dx} {dt} = - xe^{-x^2}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, wolfram-alpha

Plot the solution curves and phase portrait of $$\frac {dx} {dt} = - xe^{-x^2}$$

It seems that it's increasing for $x < 0$ and decreasing $x > 0$.

Then it seems concave down for $\frac {-1} {\sqrt{2}} < x < \frac {1} {\sqrt{2}}$ and concave up elsewhere.

It doesn't seem like that in [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dx%2Fdt%20%3D%20-%20xe%5E%7B-x%5E2%7D). I can't even seem to limit it to [$-1 < t < 1$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dx%2Fdt%20%3D%20-%20xe%5E%7B-x%5E2%7D,%20-1%20%3C%20t%20%3C%201). How do I do that? I don't think I can zoom in without a pro account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the concavity part, the second derivative of $x$ with respect to $t$ is 
$$\frac{d(-xe^{-x^2})}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}$$
This gives you 
$$-x(2x^2-1)e^{-x^2}$$

So the curve is concave up at $x<-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $0<x<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, and concave down elsewhere. This is consistent with the graph Wolfram Alpha gives.

Answer (score 2):

Your sentence "It seems that it's increasing for $x < 0$ and decreasing $x > 0$" says it all. Because of this the phase portrait has an equilibrium at $0$ and the arrows on $(0,+\infty)$ and $(-\infty,0)$ are respectively $\leftarrow$ and $\rightarrow$. Nothing else is needed for the phase portrait.

Comment: Sorry, solution curves also. Thanks Jonas

Comment: It is quite inappropriate to change the question after knowing that you have an answer... to say the least.